# Unable to open a web-page in Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, torsocks, tor-install, directory

I'm trying to open https://read.amazon.com on the latest version of Tor but I get a black screen. It works fine on Tor versions below 7. I'm wondering if I tweak the browser to get the web page to open.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a url redirection issue. 
When I open the https://read.amazon.com  link on Firefox, it redirects to https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.assoc_handle=amzn_kweb&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fread.amazon.com%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&pageId=amzn_kcr .

The black screen in Tor Browser is as a result of this redirect not happening. I suggest you copy the [redirected url](https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.assoc_handle=amzn_kweb&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fread.amazon.com%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&pageId=amzn_kcr) and paste it into Tor. It will render seamlessly.

Here's a screenshot of the pages side-by-side; on Firefox and on Tor Browser respectively. 
[image]

Comment: You are right. The  https://read.amazon.com url does redirect to the sign-in page but   after signing in it redirects back to https://read.amazon.com which again shows up as a [black screen](https://ibb.co/WxhHmJL).

Answer (score 0):

When you say "but I get a black screen", do you mean that you get the page that says "This application requires Javascript. Please turn on Javascript in your browser's preferences/settings and try again."?
If so, you would need to enable JavaScript (which may decrease your privacy/security).
If you are OK with the risk and want to disable JavaScript on that page, you would click the NoScript button, and then on the line the says "amazon.com" on the right, you would click click the "S" on the left.

Here is a video about how to use NoScript: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhJTwCFFzrE&t=174

Comment: There is nothing written on the [black screen](https://ibb.co/WxhHmJL). I have added the url as trusted in noscript, yet it still shows up the same. @PROTechThor figured out that there is a redirect but even after signing in to the redirected url, the screen turns black again.                                                                                                                      It works perfectly on [Tor 6.5](https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/6.5/) but not on versions above 7. I tried looking at the change logs but couldn't find anything.